# conditional remove duplicates

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a list where i want to remove the duplicate where "Date of Termination (Work)" column is the latest or null.

sample data

```
Id No   Name    Surname Date of Employment (Work)   Date of Termination (Work)
12405   xxxx    yyy     10/26/2018                  2/6/2019
33418   mmm     nnnn    1/1/2018                    7/30/2018
33418   mmm     nnnn    1/13/2017                   12/31/2017
33616   rrrr    sssss   7/13/2018                   11/19/2018
33616   rrrr    sssss   7/13/2018                   null
48224   ttttt   kkkk    7/15/2018                   4/14/2019
```

the result should be

```
Id No   Name    Surname Date of Employment (Work)   Date of Termination (Work)
12405   xxxx    yyy     10/26/2018                  2/6/2019
33418   mmm     nnnn    1/1/2018                    7/30/2018
33616   rrrr    sssss   7/13/2018   
48224   ttttt   kkkk    7/15/2018                   4/14/2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get expected output:

[image: Output]

using the code below:

```
let
    initialTable = Table.FromColumns({
        {12405, 33418, 33418, 33616, 33616, 48224},
        {"xxxx", "mmm", "mmm", "rrrr", "rrrr", "ttttt"},
        {"yyy", "nnnn", "nnnn", "sssss", "sssss", "kkkk"},
        {#date(2018, 10, 26), #date(2018, 01, 01), #date(2017, 1, 13), #date(2018, 7, 13), #date(2018, 7, 13), #date(2018, 7, 15)},
        {#date(2019, 02, 06), #date(2018, 7, 30), #date(2017, 12, 31), #date(2018, 11, 19), null, #date(2019, 4, 14)}
    }, type table [Id No = Int64.Type, Name = text, Surname = text, #"Date of Employment (Work)" = date, #"Date of Termination (Work)" = date]),
    nullElseMaxComparer = (x as record, y as record) =>
        let
            a = Record.Field(x, "Date of Termination (Work)"),
            b = Record.Field(y, "Date of Termination (Work)"),
            comparison = if a = null then 2 else if b = null then -2 else Value.Compare(a, b)
        in comparison,
    maxOrNullPerGroup = Table.Group(initialTable, "Id No", {"toCombine", each Table.Max(_, nullElseMaxComparer)}),
    combined = Table.FromRecords(maxOrNullPerGroup[toCombine])
in
    combined
```

- If I understand correctly, for each `ID No`, you want the latest termination date.
- In the expected output shown in the question and specifically for ID No `33616`, `null` was preferred over `11/19/2018`. So I've assumed that, for the purposes of this question, `null` is greater than any date.
- `nullElseMaxComparer` is a custom comparison function which tries to give preference to `null` values -- and can be passed directly to `Table.Max`.

Comment: thank you for your time, you understood all correctly but there is an error coming with your formula although the data is in place. 

`Expression.Error: The field 'Date Of Termination (Work)' of the record wasn't found.
Details:
    Id No=33418
    Name=xxx
    Surname=yyy
    Date of Employment (Work)=1/13/2017 12:00:00 AM
    Date of Termination (Work)=12/31/2017 12:00:00 AM
`

and this error comes with all data which the termination day is the end of day of the year.

Comment: @UmutK Might be because I've used an uppercase `O` in `Date Of Termination (Work)`, but your data seems to use a lowercase `o`. I will edit my answer to use a lowercase `o`.

Comment: if this is the case, it shouldnt be working at all, right ?

Comment: @UmutK Sorry, it's hard to say without seeing what you're seeing. Are you able to provide a copy of your workbook/file?

Comment: i couldnt find actually the file with the error. maybe this caused by other codes i've used in that file. i created a new file and tried your code. worked like a charm. thank you ! here is the file...  https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnyfkbrJQyhJqEIl9mahL51Wc5Oo?e=dcO2fI

Answer (score 0):

i found a workaround (group by max) but i am sure there is an easier and faster way

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Id No", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}, {"Surname", type text}, {"Date of Employment (Work)", type datetime}, {"Date of Termination (Work)", type datetime}, {"Duty", type text}, {"Citizenship", type text}, {"National ID", type text}, {"Passport Serial/No", type text}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Id No", Order.Ascending}, {"Date of Termination (Work)", Order.Descending}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Sorted Rows", {"Id No"}, {{"all", each _, type table [Id No=number, Name=text, Surname=text, #"Date of Employment (Work)"=datetime, #"Date of Termination (Work)"=datetime, Duty=text, Citizenship=text, National ID=text, #"Passport Serial/No"=text]}, {"maxdate", each List.Max([#"Date of Termination (Work)"]), type datetime}}),
    #"Expanded all" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "all", {"Name", "Surname", "Date of Employment (Work)", "Date of Termination (Work)", "Duty", "Citizenship", "National ID", "Passport Serial/No"}, {"Name", "Surname", "Date of Employment (Work)", "Date of Termination (Work)", "Duty", "Citizenship", "National ID", "Passport Serial/No"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded all", each ([#"Date of Termination (Work)"] = [maxdate])  ),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"maxdate"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
= Table.Distinct(Table.Sort(YourTable, {"Date of Termination (Work)", 1}), {"Id No"})
```

[image]

Comment: it removes the data with the null data as well... sorting descending ?

Comment: I've added picture. After sorting nulls go to the bottom of the table. So, for duplicated ids they are removed.

Comment: thank you for the time and effort. but we need to keep the null because this person is still working ;)  so , if it is null we should keep this row, if not, the latest date.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, maybe I provide another solution later. On my mind, you provide quite misleading information. Although the desired table is crystal clear, you also write " i want to remove the duplicate where "Date of Termination (Work)" column is the latest or null" and provide the code, which has same output as mine (dates without nulls).

Comment: right not very clear actually, it should be like "i want to remove the duplicates where if "Date of Termination (Work)" column is not null, the latest or null"